# When using join in a string, I get too many characters in the string

Tags: python, string, join

I am trying to join an underscore into a string, but when running the code I get 4 times the character i used

```
str = potetoBox

for indx in range (len(str)):
    if str[indx].isupper():
        #split before indx and input an underscore
        str = ''.join((str[:indx],'_',str[indx:]))

print(str)
```

I have tried to change characters and change the order of the code. I expected to get only one underscore.

Comment: You're changing the string while you're still iterating over it; that usually leads to weird results.  Step through the loop one iteration at a time and ask yourself what `str[indx]` is each time (remembering that you may have just entirely changed what `str` is, even though `indx` is still based on the original string and the ongoing iteration).  Also, note that `str` is not a good name for a variable because it's the name of a built-in type.

Comment: The problem is that your str changes its length while you keep inserting characters. You can also simply join around `_`:  `"_".join(str)` will insert underscores between each letter

Comment: Suppose `str` is `abcUxyz`.  When `indx` is 3, it will see the `U`, and insert `_` before it, resulting in `abc_Uxyz`.  On the next iteration, `indx` is 4, so it seels `U` a second time, in its new position.  So you get `abc__Uxyz`.  And it keeps going, until it reaches the end of the *original* length (which is another bug).  So it keeps seeing `U` over and over, then stops prematurely, never looking at the rest of the string.  This isn't a subtle bug, it's very straightforward and it would be a good exercise for you to try to reason it out, and think of how you'd go about fixing it.

Comment: I am learning Python and your answers are very explanatory. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution without re that doesn't build a list:

```
result = ""
for c in my_str:
    result += "_" * c.isupper() + c
```

Comment: Thank you for this easy to understand solution

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, with List comprehension:

```
newstr = "".join(['_'+x if x.isupper() else x for x in str])
```

Comment: `newstr = "".join('_'*x.isupper()+x for x in str)` ;-)

Comment: It is shorter, but I am not sure if it is better =) Yours is fine, explicit, legible. Mine is more of a humorous code-golf approach. Especially beginners might have to stare down what's happening there.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that completely avoids the "modification while iteration" problem uses regex:

```
import re

s = "potetoBox"
re.sub(r"([A-Z])", "_\g<1>", s)
# 'poteto_Box'

s = "potatoSaladBox"
re.sub(r"([A-Z])", "_\g<1>", s)
# 'potato_Salad_Box'
```

This [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)stitues any upper case letter `[A-Z]` with an underscore followed by the letter itself `\g<1>` (the first captured group).